# Import custom java file

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to read some source code in Java I found online to study and learn the material.  I want to compile the files first to make sure they work before I study it.  When I try to compile though, the compiler complains that it can't find some of the files it needs to import.  So opening up the main.java, I find

```
 package br.com.seimos.minijava;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import br.com.seimos.minijava.parser.MiniJavaParser;
 import br.com.seimos.minijava.syntaxtree.Program;
 import br.com.seimos.minijava.visitor.TreeDumper;
 import br.com.seimos.minijava.visitor.TreeFormatter;
```

The errors I'm getting are coming from not being able to find `MiniJavaParser`, `TreeDumper`...the 3rd chunk of code.  Those files exist in the same directory as the main file though, so what is going on?  What is `br.com.seimos.minijava` stuff?  I tried putting the files in that those folders (as in `br\com\seimos\minijava\PUT_FILES_HERE`) but still no good.  Does `br` need to be in the root directory?

Thanks, I realize this is probably a really elementary question...

Comment: Did you specify the package in MiniJavaParser etc...?

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate?  Am relatively new to Java...

Comment: In MiniJavaParser, do you specify, 
`package br.com.seimos.minijava.parser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required directory structure is `br/com/seimos/minijava/OTHER_FOLDERS/SOURCE_FILES.java`. For instance, the path to `MiniJavaParser` should be `br/com/seimos/minijava/parser/MiniJavaParser.java`. You should then run the Java compiler from the parent directory of `br`.

If you're using Eclipse or another IDE, you should configure your project settings to handle this.

Comment: Thank you!  Had to change where I was running `javac` from (I was running it from the `minijava` directory (where `main.java` was).  Thank you so much~

Answer (score 0):

For `import br.com.seimos.minijava.parser.MiniJavaParser;` your `MiniJavaParser` class must be in the directory `br\com\seimos\minijava\parser\` and not `br\com\seimos\minijava\`. Similarly for other classes. Try changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You will need to put those files in `br/com/seimos/minijava/...` as indicated by the package name of each. Java requires that you put files in a directory hierarchy that matches their package names.

Then, you'll want to compile using a command like:

```
javac br/com/seimos/minijava/parser/MiniJavaParser.java
```

This is all a bit inconvenient from the command line, especially for a larger project, so you might be better of getting a Java IDE and having it help you arrange the files.

Comment: Ohhh so you are saying we have to compile everything individually first before compiling `Main.java`?

Comment: Yes, the compiler will need to know about the contents of those other packages before compiling Main. Again, an IDE will probably help.

Comment: Nevermind!  All I had to do was change where I was running `javac` from (need to run it in the parent directory of `br`.  Thanks!~